# Custom JOptionPane Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

Java's ["How to Make Dialogs"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial shows this code:

```
//custom title, custom icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
        "Inane custom dialog", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

which would create the following dialog:

[image: Java's Example Dialog]

Why is `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE` needed when the icon will just be changed to the `icon` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag also indicates which message style to use on the window decorations, see http://nadeausoftware.com/node/91#Usinglookandfeelspecificwindowdecorations

from the JOptionPane class source code:

```
private static int styleFromMessageType(int messageType) {
    switch (messageType) {
    case ERROR_MESSAGE:
        return JRootPane.ERROR_DIALOG;
    case QUESTION_MESSAGE:
        return JRootPane.QUESTION_DIALOG;
    case WARNING_MESSAGE:
        return JRootPane.WARNING_DIALOG;
    case INFORMATION_MESSAGE:
        return JRootPane.INFORMATION_DIALOG;
    case PLAIN_MESSAGE:
    default:
        return JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG;
    }
}
```

and in the method showOptionDialog which is called by showMessageDialog...

```
int style = styleFromMessageType(messageType);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title, style);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, useful info but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The messageType is not only used for the icon, it is also used for the window decorations, which might not have an effect depending on your look&feel used.

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't quite understand that until your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there might be a number of reasons for this...for example...

It would allow the `JOptionPane` to fall back to the message type if the supplied `icon` resolved to `null` (or the underlying image couldn't be loaded for some reason).

It would allow the look and feel to ignore the `icon` and use the message type instead.